# Display the minimum value from 3 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

i have table like as follows

```
**Date        col1  col2  col3** 
1-jan-2016    -98    25     15
19-jan-2016    25    -79    20
25-dec-2015   -12    24     89
```

i have to find the minimum value from col1, col2, col3, and display the date of that record.

in this case my result should be 1-jan-2016 -98

Comment: Removed the `plsql` tag and re-tagged with `sql` and `oracle` as there is no indication that a stored procedure (which would require PL/SQL) is needed

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in plsql this way using the `LEAST` function

```
  declare
  cursor c1 is select date_column,least(col1, col2, col3) least_value from yourtable;
  BEGIN
  FOR a in c1 LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(a.date_column || ' ' || a.least_value);
  end loop;
  end;
```

you can do it in simple sql as well:

```
 select x.date_column, x.least_value from 
        (select date_column, least(col1, col2, col3) least_value from yourtable) x
            where x.least_value = (select min(least_value) from  
                                      (select least(col1, col2, col3) least_value from yourtable))
```

Comment: Hi Vance, thanks for your reply, but i want only one min value from the table, my result should be (date and min value)1-jan-2016  -98

Comment: It's basic. You can use the `min` function and a little bit of subquerying. I have updated the sql part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEAST between col1,col2 and col3, MIN to get the lowest from all the rows and the MIN....KEEP to get the date column associated with that minimum.

```
with src as
   (select to_date(' 1-jan-2016','dd-mon-yyyy') col_d, -98 col1,   25 col2, 15 col3 from dual union all
   select to_date('19-jan-2016','dd-mon-yyyy') col_d,  25 col1,  -79 col2, 20 col3 from dual union all
   select to_date('25-dec-2015','dd-mon-yyyy') col_d, -12 col1,   24 col2, 89 col3 from dual)
select min(least(col1,col2,col3)) least,
       min(col_d) keep (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY least(col1,col2,col3) ) col_d
from src;
```